# Display list of related entities in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

I have a Table ECmain that has a relationship with 2 other tables, Notes and Email.

I want to access the data in the view so that a list of toes will appear for every record in ECmain and be editable.

Here is my Model

```
namespace EditSuite.Models

{
public class ECmain
{

    public ECmain()
{
    this.Notes = new Collection<Notes>();
}

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Auth { get; set; }
    public string KeyWords { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Live { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Email> Email { get; set; }
    public List<Notes> NoteList { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ECmainID { get; set; }
    public string EmailText { get; set; }

    public virtual ECmain ECmain { get; set; }

}


public class Notes
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ECmainID { get; set; }
    public string NotesText { get; set; }

    public virtual ECmain Ecmain { get; set; }
}
```

DB Context

```
namespace EditSuite.DAL
{
public class ECContext : DbContext
{

    public ECContext()
        : base("name=ECmodelConnection")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ECmain> ECmain { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Email> Email { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Notes> Notes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
}
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using EditSuite.DAL;
using EditSuite.Models;

namespace EditSuite.Controllers
{
    public class ECmainsController : Controller
    {
        private ECContext db = new ECContext();

        // GET: ECmain
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //var church = from m in db.ECmain.Take(10)
            //             where m.Live == "Y" && m.Auth == "Yes"
            //             select m;
            //church = church.OrderBy(m => m.Category);
            return View(db.ECmain.Take(10));

        }
```

View

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KeyWords)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.URL)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubCategory)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Live)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The result is 
Server Error in '/' Application.

Invalid column name 'ECmain_ID1'.
Invalid column name 'ECmain_ID1'.
Invalid column name 'ECmain_ID'.
Invalid column name 'ECmain_ID1'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'ECmain_ID1'.
Invalid column name 'ECmain_ID1'.
Invalid column name 'ECmain_ID'.
Invalid column name 'ECmain_ID1'

I tried 
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NoteList)
But that returned nothing

Comment: Please check the column names on these tables `ECmain, Email and Notes` has anyone a coulmn with the name `ECmain_ID1` or `ECmain_ID`. Could you add the sql-statement generated by EF?

Comment: There are no fields with that name, there are 3 One to many related tables, ECmain, Email and Notes. ECmainID is a field in Email and Notes keyed to ID in ECmain. The display returns the rows in ECmain but I want to add a column that displays a list of Notes and Emails for that record As the dB is normalized. Perhaps another foreach loop at this column? @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like this problem:
[ASP.NET MVC /Entity Framework Error - Invalid column name 'Environment_Id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010658/asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-error-invalid-column-name-environment-id)

The answer there may be helpful to you.

Gerry

#### 3rd Party Edit

For me the answer linked by Gerry could be of use to your problem. I have not worked much with EF and MVC but based on your Exception `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'ECmain_ID1'` or `'ECmain_ID'` i assume

- that the sql statement that is created by [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) does not match the columns in your database
- or that the matching between table-columns from your sql-result and the properties of you email-object fails

Comment: I changed the model per this post to     `public class Email
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ECmainID { get; set; }
        public string EmailText { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ECmainID")]
        public virtual ECmain ECmain { get; set; }

    }


    public class Notes
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ECmainID { get; set; }
        public string NotesText { get; set; }
         [ForeignKey("ECmainID")]
        public virtual ECmain Ecmain { get; set; }
    }` same results.