# asp mvc5 adding a table to existing project for dropdown list data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using an asp MVC5 project, has a working SQL table.  Question is how can a 2nd table be added in such that it holds commonly used data such as name, phone, email etc;  Goal is to have dropdowns on the main project on a View page so that they will populate or "auto fill" the related fields for name, email etc.

```
 [Table("newInfoTable")]
public class InfoTable
{

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Contact Phone Number")]
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

In the main table, there is a reference to this table:

```
    public virtual ICollection<InfoTable> InfoTableDat { get; set; }
```

And all of the variable names in this new info table match names in the Main project table.  The new SQL table was created with SQL Management Studio, tested, made a new controller/view and am able to add items/edit or delete to this table from the project.

Within the View, an Edit page, intellisense can see the @Model.InfoTableDat But how to fill the dropdown list?

And is it correct to use "public virtual ICollectioninstanceName" or does that simply link the 2 tables based on the ID? It gets an error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Invalid column name 'MainProj_ID'.
>        Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the      current web request. Please review the stack trace for
>   more information about the      error and where it originated in the
>   code.

The main project class is named MainProj.cs in the Model folder, but there's no MainProj_ID, I never use the underscore for any names.

Comment: I'm unsure what you want the dropdown to contain? You can use the @Html.DropDownFor() method to create a dropdown, but you need to create a SelectList in the controller for this to work. You say you want to auto fill the related fields. This can be done using jQuery (javascript) or done in the controller, based on the value of the dropdown

Comment: Yes, the dropdown should contain just the First, Last Names, then phone number and possibly email, the user clicks and all the names appear.  Click on any item, and it becomes the selected row;  Jquery could then fill those corresponding variables, iterating thru the selected row.  Just getting that selected row is the challenge.  And now more columns are needed in the table which i can figure out, but at least First,Last Name should appear on the dropdown.  When clicked the other column items not shown will be put into corresponding fields in that View page

Comment: So you want a dropdown with the value of FirstName + LastName. And then when you select one of these, the other fields on the page gets the value of the corresponding person selected in the dropdown?

Comment: As for the other problem, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010658/asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-error-invalid-column-name-environment-id

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correct, this is how i would do it.
You need a dropdown of all your InfoTableDat rows, where the text of each option is the full name from the infotable and the value is the ID

Thefore you have to add the following field to your InfoTable model:

```
[NotMapped]
public string FullName {
    get {
        return firstName + " " + LastName
    }
}
```

This makes sure that you have a full name you can use as the text. To get the data from the dropdownlist you have to add the following to your action in your controller:

```
ViewBag.InfoTables = new SelectList(Model.InfoTableDat, "FullName", "ID");
```

The "FullName" is the field for the text and "ID" is the field for the value of the dropdown

To display the dropdown the following HtmlHelper is used:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Model.InfoTableDatID, (SelectList)ViewBag.InfoTables)
```

To make all of this work, you need a eventlistener in jQuery for when the dropdown changes. This event then needs to do an AJAX call to a method that gets the detail for the specific InfoTable with the ID of the selected option in the dropdown. When youve fetched the data via. AJAX, all there's left is to append the data to the existing fields in your view.

That's how i would do it

Comment: ok, but in the main Edit form all it 'sees' is the other, 'main' database table.  Trying to get access to another table's data I could not figure out how.

Comment: Thanks Soren,  I have been putting this idea into the code and testing to make it work. Had thought of ViewBag so thats great.  Apparently there was some problem with all my efforts to ask this, and someone found it necessary to down vote me for trying to follow all the requirements for asking a question.  Perhaps that's just the setup here, a lack of professionalism is pervasive.