# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Faculty_Id'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Terms,Semester,Sections,Course,CreditHourTheory,CreditHourLab,Labinstructor,Faculty,Rooms,Day,Date,TimeStart,TimeEnd")] TimeTable.Models.TimeTable timetable)    
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TimeTable.Add(timetable);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        return View(timetable);

    }
```

In the view i have use the dropdown to get the value from the database and to insert this selected value in the another table in database

```
@Html.DropDownList("FId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control input-md cc2", @disabled = "disabled", @required = "" })
```

Model:

```
[Table("TimeTable")]
public class TimeTable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Terms { get; set; }
    public string Semester { get; set; }


    public int SectionsId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SectionsId")]
    public Sections Sections { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    public string CreditHourTheory { get; set; }

    public string CreditHourLab { get; set; }

    public int? LabInstructorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LabInstructorId")]
    public Faculty Labinstructor { get; set; }

    public int FacultyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FacultyId")]
    public Faculty Faculty { get; set; }

    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoomId")]
    public Rooms Rooms { get; set; }


    public string Day { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan TimeStart { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan TimeEnd { get; set; }
}
```

Server Error in '/' Application.

Invalid column name 'Faculty_Id'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Faculty_Id'.

Source Error:

Line 54:             {

Line 55:                 db.TimeTable.Add(timetable);

Line 56:                 await db.SaveChangesAsync();

Line 57:                 return RedirectToAction("Create");

Line 58:             }

Source File: c:\Users\NoorMuhammad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TimeTable\TimeTable\Controllers\HomeController.cs    Line: 56

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Faculty_Id'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.b__24(Task`1 result) +1792654
   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke() +81
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() +45
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +123
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.d__0.MoveNext() +1068
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +71
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.d__0.MoveNext() +676

[UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.d__0.MoveNext() +1044
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +66
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.d__3d`1.MoveNext() +1138
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +66
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<SaveChangesToStoreAsync>d__39.MoveNext() +619
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +24
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext() +457
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +66
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.d__31.MoveNext() +1165

[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   TimeTable.Controllers.<Create>d__8.MoveNext() in c:\Users\NoorMuhammad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TimeTable\TimeTable\Controllers\HomeController.cs:56
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +114
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274

Comment: Noor, Just a suggestion have u looked into this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010658/asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-error-invalid-column-name-environment-id?rq=1http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010658/asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-error-invalid-column-name-environment-id?rq=1

Comment: i already seen this but can't get it

Comment: in my case my project namespace is also "TimeTable"

Comment: i have changed the class name and model name from "TimeTable" to "Lecture" but the error remain same